# WebControl request through custom Socket implementation

Tags: android, ios, web, windows-mobile, socketfactory

This question is broad and cover three major mobile operating system (Android,iOS, Windows Mobile).

So for WebView (Android), UIWebView (iOS), WebBrowser ? (Windows Mobile) controls, I want to intercept the web request and send it through my own custom Socket Implementation.

I want to check if all these OS provide this functionality before making decisions on how the application should work.

The application is intended to be a hybrid app that shows some mobile specific controls for navigation and then a web page where the actual contents are needed to be displayed.

But I want to tunnel these requests through my socket implementation rather then sending it through default address/port.

If custom socket factory is not possibility here, than what other options do I have here. I have looked around on internet a little and the closest I got was to adding headers in request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Android world, you may provide your own WebViewClient object to the WebView and shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returns true for your host application to handle the URL.

Comment: what about other systems?